# Trouble with pickup physics in unity c# script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object, pickup

I am a beginner in unity scripting and I am having troubles with making a code on how to pick up an object.

I have ran through 4-5 YouTube tutorials and still cannot manage to pick up objects. When I try to pick up objects, there is no movements of the object at all. The object has mesh collider, mesh renderer and a rigidbody. I created a character with the character controller, character script and a crosshair. I made the character according to the brackeys 1st person movement tutorial video on youtube.
The moving script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CharacterController controller;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;

        controller.Move(move);
    }
}
```

The mouselook script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MouseLook : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float mouseSensitivity = 1000f;

    public Transform playerBody;

    float xRotation = 0f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;

        xRotation -= mouseY;
        xRotation = Mathf.Clamp(xRotation, -90f, 90f);

        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
        playerBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);
    }
}
```

I wanted a script that can make my character pick up an object from the scene.[What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Fxlm.png)

Comment: Hi, if you've watched 4-5 tutorials and gained no information either you managed to pick the 4-5 worst on youtube or you are not grasping the concepts.  SO is not a code writing service we will not be providing scripts nor is it on topic to ask for tutorials.  None of your code here is about picking up an object.

Comment: Thanks. I will try searching for more specific tutorials or try coding it my self.